# Get localisation strings from ms Office or Windows in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, translation, multilingual

I was programming multilingual application using Visual Basic.NET, so I was wondering if I can use the localisation's strings of Microsoft Office or Windows instead of making a translation for a lot of languages.

So, the application first will check if the display language is not English, then if it was true, it will show the application strings in the current display language by getting the strings from the windows strings.

It does not matter if some of my application's strings do not exist in windows strings.

Thanks.